# How can I get the error message out of Http.Error?

Tags: elm

I'm attempting to complete an exercise in the [Elm 0.17 tutorial for HTTP](http://guide.elm-lang.org/architecture/effects/http.html). If fetching a gif fails, I would like to let the user know why it failed with an error message.

I've modified my model to be:

```
type alias Model =
  { topic : String
  , gifUrl : String
  , errorMessage : String
  }
```

And fetch fail in update to be:

```
FetchFail error ->
  (Model model.topic model.gifUrl (errorMessage error), Cmd.none)
```

Where the function `errorMessage` is as follows:

```
errorMessage : Http.Error -> String
errorMessage error =
  case error of
    Http.Timeout ->
      "Timeout"
    Http.NetworkError  ->
      "Network Error"
    Http.UnexpectedPayload _ ->
      "UnexpectedPayload"
    Http.BadResponse _ _ ->
      "BadResponse"
```

The above function seems like unnecessary boiler plate to me. Is there a way that I can directly convert `Http.Error` into a string?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert anything to a string using [`toString`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Basics#toString). That will give you nearly the same output as your case statements:

```elm
toString Timeout == "Timeout"
toString NetworkError == "NetworkError"
toString (UnexpectedPayload "Error") == "UnexpectedPayload \"Error\"" 
toString (BadResponse 500 "Error") == "BadResponse 500 \"Error\""
```

Just replace the call to `errorMessage` with `toString` and you can get rid of `errorMessage` entirely:

```elm
FetchFail error ->
  (Model model.topic model.gifUrl (toString error), Cmd.none)
```

Comment: If the response was a `BadResponse 400 """{"errors": ["missing required argument q"]"""`, the boilerplate @Martimatix used will be required, no? In essence, the response would is an `Either Error a`.

Comment: If you wanted to omit the parameters and just print "BadResponse", then yes, you would have to explicitly call that out in a case statement, and you could have an underscore catch-all case that then defaults to `toString`.

Comment: `toString` was changed to the `Debug` module as of version 0.19.